# Group concat query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I had results after query success

table user :

[image]

And with results. I want join to table subjects get subject name by id.

table Subjects :

[image]

Id of table user related with table Subjects

Output I want :

[image]

Can you give me query. Thanks all !

Comment: Can you show the full first table, along with your expected output?

Comment: Try it yourself. Here is what you could read about Joins in MySQL in order to understand. https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: Provide how your raw data and the result should look like ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I don't show full table because data is secret. But I can say this table have fields userId, userName, and defaultSujectId of user. I stucking at  value "2, 5".

Comment: You at least need to show us what output you want.  By the way, don't store your data as CSV because it makes it hard to work with.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated question above.

Comment: I gave an answer below using whatever data you showed us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing CSV data in your MySQL table, which is not desirable.  But one way you can work with it is to join the `Subjects` table to the `user` table using `FIND_IN_SET` to handle the CSV data contained in the latter.

```
SELECT t2.defaultSubjectId,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t1.subject)
FROM Subjects t1
INNER JOIN user t2
    ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.subjectId, t2.defaultSubjectId) > 0
GROUP BY t2.defaultSubjectId
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Thank for answer and I testing it. if don't work i will post raw data for you

Comment: In the future you should avoid using CSV data.  In this particular case, we were able to work around it using `FIND_IN_SET`, but if you ever had to join two columns, both of which had CSV, you would have a very hard time doing that in MySQL.

Comment: I will remember it :). Thanks again